# send notification email to specific user mail in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, notifications, email-notifications

i need to send the email for the owner of product when user order this product... everything works well, but really i dont know the idea.... this is the Notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class OrderNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    private $insertOrderData;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($insertOrderData)
    {
        $this->insertOrderData = $insertOrderData;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line($this->insertOrderData['info'])
                    ->action($this->insertOrderData['user_id'], url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and here my controller, and the method when user make an order for the product:

```
public function store( Product $product, Request $request)
    {
$orderData = [
    'info' => $request->info,
    'min' => $request->min,
    'max' => $request->max,
    'file' => $file_name,
    'product_id' => $product->id,
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'owner_id' => $product->user->id
];
            try {
                Order::create($orderData)->save();
                $product->user->notify(new OrderNotification($order_file));
                return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', 'your orders has been sent successfully');
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'this product has already in your order list');
            }
```

so here :

```
$product->user->notify(new OrderNotification($order_file));
```

i have tried to send a notification since the

```
$product->user
```

is the user who own the product and i need to send a notification to his email, and surly he has an email field in the migration>>> so my question how can i do that?

Comment: Try to `dd($e->getMessage())` after `}catch (\Exception $e) {`. I think it's because `$order_file` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: yes , it is a mistake, but not here my problem, i dont have idea at all about how to send it to the specific email? i didn't find anything about that

Comment: sorry, it is working, like you have said, just this problem... thank you